# Someone made a FaceTime call with my number

Tags: security, apple-id, facetime

My husband told me that he received a FaceTime call from my number but he missed the call. I never called him and I don't have any outgoing calls in my phone or anything. Is my Apple ID compromised?

Comment: Possibly? Check other devices you have associated with that Apple ID - iPads and Macs - which could also make FaceTime calls. If you're worried, [change your Apple ID password](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5624), and check the list of email addresses associated with your Apple ID.

Answer (score 2):

First double check with your hubby if the call came from your FaceTime.

If it was, and you have no records, then do [reset your account](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5624) (new strong password would be good).